# Specify list of allowed nodes for Slurm job

Tags: slurm

Is it possible to specify a list of allowed nodes when submitting a single-node job?  I.e. the job should be restricted to run on one of the listed nodes (basically the complement to `--exclude`).

I first thought that `--nodelist` is what I need but there it tries to use *all* specified nodes instead of just picking one of them (thus listing multiple nodes there is incompatible with `--nodes=1`).

Comment: No AFAIK. You will have to generate the complementary node list and use `--exclude`.

Comment: Indeed, I just found https://bugs.schedmd.com/show_bug.cgi?id=998, which confirms that this feature does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the current version of the documentation does not reflect that, the latest Slurm version to date (23.02) allows specifying more nodes in `-w/--nodelist` than needed by `-N/--nodes`.

The change log for `23.02.0rc1` indeed indicates:

> Allow for --nodelist to contain more nodes than required by --nodes.

And I can confirm it works on a cluster with Slurm `23.02.6`:

```
[user@cluster ~]$ srun -N1 -w node0[11-15] hostname
node015
[user@cluster ~]$
```

Answer (score 1):

According to https://bugs.schedmd.com/show_bug.cgi?id=998, there is no such option in Slurm.